# Using hystrix-javanica annotations on interfaces

Tags: java, annotations, hystrix

I am integrating Hystrix into [SilverWare](http://www.silverware.io/) microservices platform and I want to use [hystrix-javanica](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica) annotations. These annotations are meant to be applied on the actual implementation of the methods that need to be executed using Hystrix. The problem is that I need to implement a generic solution where you only have a service interface. It has to be done this way in order to let developers use annotated references to other microservices (when they implement their own service) without any need to deal with the implementation of those services.

I came up with a solution where you annotate your microservice reference with something like this:

```java
@Inject
@MicroserviceReference
@HystrixConfiguration(MyServiceHystrix.class)
private MyService myService;
```

And then you implement (or extend) the service interface and put Hystrix annotations on its methods:

```java
public interface HystrixedMyService extends MyService {
    @HystrixCommand
    doSomething();
}
```

When there is `@HystrixConfiguration` annotation on a field in your microservice referencing another service, SilverWare will scan the class given as a parameter of this annotation and prepare a Hystrix command for every method of the service. The command will also receive a callable with an actual method invocation which will be executed in its `run()` method.

**My question is:** Is it possible to reuse some (internal) parts of hystrix-javanica so I do not need to scan all the annotations and create those Hystrix commands myself? I can see that most of the classes are designed to be used only with AOP.

Comment: Hi, I guess it's possible, HystrixCommand is inherited annotation so that you don't need to define it for each implementation. If you can setup AOP in your project then everything should work, have you tried using AOP with javanica with SilverWare ?

Comment: We do not want to mess with AOP in SilverWare. I have finally implemented it on my own with slightly modified Hystrix annotations and without a dependency on `hystrix-javanica`. It should appear in the next version of SilverWare.